# Docker-compose, Java and Redis - Connection refused issue

Tags: java, docker, redis, docker-compose

I'm struggling for whole day with some docker compose basic config - containers linking. Unfortunately results are haggard.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  webapp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    networks:
      - net
    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - net

networks:
  net:
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/hello-docker.war app.war
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.war'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.war"]
```

IndexController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String index(Model model) {
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis("redis", 6379);

        jedis.set("key1", "some value");

        model.addAttribute("rValue", jedis.get("key1"));

        return "index";
    }
}
```

When accessing localhost:8084 from my browser I'm getting connection refused error.

Redis log:

> redis_1   | 1:C 03 Mar 2019 16:08:24.441 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is
>   starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
>   redis_1   | 1:C 03 Mar 2019 16:08:24.441 #
>   Redis version=5.0.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just
>   started
>   redis_1   | 1:C 03 Mar 2019 16:08:24.441 # Warning: no config
>   file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config
>   file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
>   redis_1   | 1:M 03 Mar 2019
>   16:08:24.442 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
>   redis_1   | 1:M 03
>   Mar 2019 16:08:24.442 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of 511 cannot
>   be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower
>   value of 128.
>   redis_1   | 1:M 03 Mar 2019 16:08:24.442 # Server
>   initialized
>   redis_1   | 1:M 03 Mar 2019 16:08:24.442 # WARNING you
>   have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This
>   will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this
>   issue run the command 'echo never >
>   /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to
>   your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot.
>   Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
>   redis_1   | 1:M 03 Mar
>   2019 16:08:24.442 * Ready to accept connections

App log (error):

> webapp_1  | 2019-03-03 16:08:37.340 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)]
>   with root cause
>   webapp_1  | java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused (Connection refused)

Please, do someone know, what I'm doing wrong. I really went through many sites related with this topic but I didn't found any functional solution. I will be grateful for any hint.

OS: Windows 10, 64-bits
Docker v.18.09.2
Docker-compose v.1.23.2

Comment: what is the os that you used ?.

Comment: Windows 10, 64-bits. In question I also added Docker version.

Comment: Maybe run once `docker-compose rm` and also `docker network prune` to clean up docker networks. You can also try `version: '2'` at the beginning of your `docker-compose.yaml`  since you are not using any special feature from later versions.

Comment: @webwurst I've followed your suggestions but unfortunately issue still persist.

Comment: @zach Can you provide all the files and a short build instruction for your project?

Comment: @webwurst thanks for your help. I found the reason... I made a mistake in my pom file which resulted in that .war was not built properly.